# git Error: Permission denied (publickey) appeared

Tags: github

Good day,
Problem  with git is:

```
git push
Agent admitted failure to sign using the key.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I can't say that i altered my system (it used to work perfectly fine)
When i compare `ssh-add -l` and my key on https://github.com/settings/ssh i see that there are two keys attached to my account, one of them is identical to prev output.

Update 1
Generating new key didn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me https://help.github.com/articles/error-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign